# Python BeautifulSoup extraction

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have used the following code to access the description that is posted bellow.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://www.meteoclimatic.net/feed/rss/ESCYL2400000024153A')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features='xml')
items = soup.findAll('item')
print(items[0].description)
```

I have obtained the following XML sample:

```
<description>

     &lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;img src="http://meteoclimatic.net/img/sem_tpv.png" style="width: 12px; height: 12px; border: 0px;" alt="***" /&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.meteoclimatic.net/perfil/ESCYL2400000024153A"&gt;Sta Mar&amp;#237;a del Condado&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt; Actualizado: 24-07-2018 08:20 UTC&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Temperatura: &lt;b&gt;23,6&lt;/b&gt; &amp;#186;C (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;23,6&lt;/b&gt; /
M&amp;#237;n.: &lt;b style="color: blue"&gt;12,1&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Humedad: &lt;b&gt;54,0&lt;/b&gt; % (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;91,0&lt;/b&gt; /
M&amp;#237;n.: &lt;b style="color: blue"&gt;54,0&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Bar&amp;#243;metro: &lt;b&gt;1021,0&lt;/b&gt; hPa (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;1021,2&lt;/b&gt; /
M&amp;#237;n.: &lt;b style="color: blue"&gt;1019,9&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Viento: &lt;b&gt;1,0&lt;/b&gt; km/h (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;9,0&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Direcci&amp;#243;n del viento: &lt;b&gt;170&lt;/b&gt; - S&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Precip.: &lt;b&gt;0,0&lt;/b&gt; mm&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
     &lt;/ul&gt;

<!--
[[<BEGIN:ESCYL2400000024153A:DATA>]]
[[<ESCYL2400000024153A;(23,6;23,6;12,1;sun);(54,0;91,0;54,0);(1021,0;1021,2;1019,9);(1,0;9,0;170);(0,0);Sta Mar&#237;a del Condado>]]
[[<END:ESCYL2400000024153A:DATA>]]
-->
</description>
```

I want to extract the items contained between the labels `[[<BEGIN:ESCYL2400000024153A:DATA>]]` and `[[<END:ESCYL2400000024153A:DATA>]]`. How could I do that in a "pythonic" way without having to manually parse every item as a string?

Edit:

The data I want to extract may also be found in this part of the soup:

```
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;img src="http://meteoclimatic.net/img/sem_tpv.png" style="width: 12px; height: 12px; border: 0px;" alt="***" /&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.meteoclimatic.net/perfil/ESCYL2400000024153A"&gt;Sta Mar&amp;#237;a del Condado&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt; Actualizado: 24-07-2018 08:50 UTC&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Temperatura: &lt;b&gt;24,4&lt;/b&gt; &amp;#186;C (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;24,5&lt;/b&gt; /
M&amp;#237;n.: &lt;b style="color: blue"&gt;12,1&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Humedad: &lt;b&gt;49,0&lt;/b&gt; % (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;91,0&lt;/b&gt; /
M&amp;#237;n.: &lt;b style="color: blue"&gt;49,0&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Bar&amp;#243;metro: &lt;b&gt;1021,0&lt;/b&gt; hPa (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;1021,2&lt;/b&gt; /
M&amp;#237;n.: &lt;b style="color: blue"&gt;1019,9&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Viento: &lt;b&gt;5,0&lt;/b&gt; km/h (
M&amp;#225;x.: &lt;b style="color: red"&gt;10,0&lt;/b&gt; )&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Direcci&amp;#243;n del viento: &lt;b&gt;219&lt;/b&gt; - SW&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Precip.: &lt;b&gt;0,0&lt;/b&gt; mm&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
     &lt;/ul&gt;
```

Comment: These are inside an XML comment `<!-- -->`, they are *not* part of the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with BeautifulSoup, using the `Comment` object:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

resp = requests.get('https://www.meteoclimatic.net/feed/rss/ESCYL2400000024153A')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'xml')
for item in soup.select('item'):
    comments = item.description.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
    print([c for c in comments[0].split('\n') if c][1:-1])
```

Prints:

```
['[[<ESCYL2400000024153A;(24,4;24,5;12,1;sun);(49,0;91,0;49,0);(1021,0;1021,2;1019,9);(5,0;10,0;219);(0,0);Sta Mar&#237;a del Condado>]]']
```

Edit:

This code iterates through all `<item>` tags. In each `<item>` tag it will find in `<description>` all texts, that's instance of `Comment` object (in other words anything that is between `<!--` and `-->` tags. Then it will split first comment according newlines and writes all lines but first and last.

Comment: Hello, could you please do a little bit of explanation of what you are doing in here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) to get the XML comment in the `description` element.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("so.xml")

comment = tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item/description/comment()")[0].text
print(comment.split("\n")[2])
```

Output:

```
[[<ESCYL2400000024153A;(24,4;24,5;12,1;sun);(49,0;91,0;49,0);(1021,0;1021,2;1019,9);(5,0;10,0;219);(0,0);Sta Mar&#237;a del Condado>]]
```